# Limit azure portal access for VM management

Tags: permissions, azure

I am looking on the possibility to limit the access to the Azure portal to to the VM owner for VM management to allow only Start, Stop and Restart the VM actions.

Currently the RBAC doesn't allow it. I can restrict the access to some actions but not all of them e.g. "Backup".

What is the best approach to reach this goal?

Thank you,
Yannick

Answer (score 0):

You’ll likely have to create a custom role for this
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles